# Chrome's "Show in Folder" opens Dolphin after Kde Plasma Install

Tags: gnome, kde, filemanager, plasma, dolphin

I installed KDE Plasma and I used it for some time, but when I switched back to GNOME, I eventually realized that when I download things when using Google Chrome and select the "show in folder" option, it opens `dolphin`, which is KDE Plasma's file manager! How do  I make it so Google Chrome uses GNOME's file manager instead of KDE's?

Comment: How exactly did you switch back to GNOME? Changing desktop environments on an installed system can get messy.  This is why there are several official Ubuntu flavors with different desktop environments. If you don't want dolphin, you can just uninstall it. `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt remove dolphin` You can also (re)install GNOME files if you need to.

Comment: To change desktop environments, I logged out, then started to log back in by clicking my name, then I clicked the settings gear that showed all desktop environments and chose GNOME.

Comment: So you didn't actually uninstall KDE?  Do you need dolphin? Could you uninstall it?